# LWJGL executable jar starts then crashes

Tags: jar, crash, lwjgl

I would love some help with this. I developed this program for class that reads in four .obj files and one file for a texture. It works fine in my IDE (Eclipse) but when i export it and use JavaSplice to create the final executable jar, it launches, shows a display window for a fraction of a second, then just crashes. With some testing and careful commenting, I've determined that it is not on the splicing end but rather my code. With commenting, I've determined that the problem lies in the Display Lists that read in the four .obj:

```
int objectOneDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
glNewList(objectOneDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);
{   
        Model m = null;
        try
        {
            m = OBJLoader.loadModel(new File("res/circle.obj"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
        }

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for(Face face : m.faces)
        {
            glColor3f(0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f);
            Vector3f n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.x - 1);
            glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
            Vector3f v1 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.x - 1);
            glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
            Vector3f n2 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.y - 1);
            glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
            Vector3f v2 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.y - 1);
            glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
            Vector3f n3 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.z - 1);
            glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
            Vector3f v3 = m.vertices.get((int) face.vertex.z - 1);
            glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glEndList();
```

There are four of those just with different filenames and list names. Now here is my OBJLoader Class:

```
package base;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;


public class OBJLoader
{
    public static Model loadModel(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        Model m = new Model();
        String line;
       while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
       {
            if(line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.vertices.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.normals.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                Vector3f vertexIndices = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]),
                Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]),
                Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]));
                Vector3f normalIndices = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]),
                Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]),
                Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]));

                m.faces.add(new Face(vertexIndices, normalIndices));
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return m;
    }
}
```

I think it is because I need to use InputFileStream. Could someone show me how I would rewrite this using that?

EDIT: Rewrote the OBJLoader to not use FileReader, still didn't work. I think I can't use any sort of Reader. How can I read the lines then?:

```
public class OBJLoader
{
    public static Model loadModel(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
        Model m = new Model();
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.startsWith("v "))
            {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.vertices.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("vn "))
            {
                float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
                float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
                float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
                m.normals.add(new Vector3f(x, y, z));
            }
            else if(line.startsWith("f "))
            {
                Vector3f vertexIndices = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]));
                Vector3f normalIndices = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]),
                        Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]));

                m.faces.add(new Face(vertexIndices, normalIndices));
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return m;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt, type:

```
java -jar "pathToYourJar.jar"
```

With this you can see what Exception the code throws.

About the crash, i think the problem can be resolved using InputStreams instead of Files.

Change:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
    (new FileInputStream(f)));
```

into

```
String path = "/package1/package2/file.obj";
InputStream source = ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
    (source);
```

This will work both in Eclipse and with JARs.